# How can three datasets with two key columns be merged without duplicating common columns?

Tags: r, merge

I have one large dataset I need to complete with information from two other smaller datasets. The large dataset would be like

```
df_large <- data.frame(letters = letters[1:5],
                       numbers = 1:5,
                       client = c("client1", "client2", "client3", "client4", "client4"),
                       other = c("other1", "other2", "other1", "other4", "other4")
                       )
```

That would be completed with information from two other smaller datasets like

```
df2 <- data.frame(numbers = 1:3,
                  info = c("info1", "info2", "info3"),
                  invoice = c(100, 150, 200))
```

and

```
df3 <- data.frame(letters = letters[4:5],
                  info = c("info4", "info5"),
                  product = c("phone", "laptop"))
```

I need to merge the two smaller datasets and use them to complete the information in the largest one. The problem is that the key is not the same for both tables: one has the variable `numbers` and the other one has the variable `letters`. So I expect a results like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 6
  letters numbers client  other  info  product
  <chr>     <int> <chr>   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  
1 a             1 client1 other1 info1    NA     
2 b             2 client2 other2 info2    NA     
3 c             3 client3 other1 info3    NA     
4 d             4 client4 other4 info4    phone  
5 e             5 client4 other4 info5    laptop
```

What I tried:
First I did `left_join(df_large, df2)`, which works well and produces the expected result with these two tables. When joining with the third, however, some information is missing:

```
test_table <- left_join(df_large, df2)  #this works well
result <- left_join(test_table, df3,
                    by = "letters")
```

The code above produces a table where the common columns in `df2` and `df3` are renamed to `info.x` and `info.y` instead of merged, like this:

```
# A tibble: 5 × 8
  letters numbers client  other  info.x invoice info.y product
  <chr>     <int> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl> <chr>  <chr>  
1 a             1 client1 other1 info1      100 NA     NA     
2 b             2 client2 other2 info2      150 NA     NA     
3 c             3 client3 other1 info3      200 NA     NA     
4 d             4 client4 other4 NA          NA info4  phone  
5 e             5 client4 other4 NA          NA info5  laptop
```

How can the common columns can be kept as common columns without losing any information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right If you carefully read this thread, you will get a general idea and, of course, the answer to your particular coding problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have joined `df_large` to `df2`, you are just filling in `NA` values from another table. One way to approach this is to use [`dplyr::rows_update()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html).

> `rows_update()` modifies existing rows (like `UPDATE` [in SQL]). Key values in `y` must be unique, and, by default, key values in `y` must exist in x.

```r
df_large |>
    left_join(df2, by = "numbers") |>
    mutate(product = NA_character_) |>
    rows_update(df3, by = "letters")

#   letters numbers  client  other  info invoice product
# 1       a       1 client1 other1 info1     100    <NA>
# 2       b       2 client2 other2 info2     150    <NA>
# 3       c       3 client3 other1 info3     200    <NA>
# 4       d       4 client4 other4 info4      NA   phone
# 5       e       5 client4 other4 info5      NA  laptop
```